# How to compare signals from RF 433 with variable codes by Arduino keeloq

Tags: arduino, signals, radio-transmission

I have Arduino with some RF 433 receiver and 433 remote to my gate (Moovo/Nice - chip EG301).

I can read codes from this remote, but every next click (on the same button) generate diffrent codes:

```
Canal C Serie D Rolling Code EDC9976E
Canal C Serie D Rolling Code 760643E1
Canal C Serie D Rolling Code 516B67F9
Canal C Serie D Rolling Code 84AAE281
```

Clear signals in HEX:

```
Received 65 bits (x1): 01 0a ea a3 34 9f ff ff fd
Received 17 bits (x1): 01 0a ea
Received 65 bits (x1): 00 50 b2 58 a6 9f ff ff fd
Received 17 bits (x1): 00 50 b2
Received 65 bits (x1): 00 e0 6f 9e 28 9f ff ff fd
Received 17 bits (x1): 00 e0 6f
```

How can I 'save' my remote and recognize it next time?

EDIT:

My reveiver is simple module MX-RM-5V.

If I good searched, signal from remote is encrypted by keeloq.

Maybe I need special reveiver with handle keeloq?

Comment: You are basically asking us how to retrieve the key from the remote, which is too broad of a question and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling code is a protocol that roll codes to make it harder to replicate the remote control.

As you probably know, you can go to any store selling remotes and buy a copyable remote for fixed codes, and for these type of devices your program will suffice, but not for rolling codes.